# Find and Insert into list class collection?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have class called GroupSelect and made a collection `List(Of GroupSelect)()`.

Now I need to find `GroupSelect` with `RowNo` and `GroupNo` in `List(Of GroupSelect)()`. If I found at same index update `Value`. If not found add to `List(Of GroupSelect)`.

```
Public Class GroupSelect
    Public Property RowNo() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_RowNo
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_RowNo = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_RowNo As Integer
    Public Property GroupNo() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_GroupNo
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_GroupNo = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_GroupNo As Integer

    Private m_Value As Integer
    Public Property Value() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_Value
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_Value = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Find this Object in the colleaction

```
                grpSelect.RowNo = rowNo
                grpSelect.GroupNo = grpNo
                grpSelect.Value = CType(CType(row.FindControl("txtCombine"), 
TextBox).Text, Integer)
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming collection is your `List(Of GroupSelect)` and `RowNo` , `GroupNo` are the values  you are checking againt and `Value` is the new value

```
Dim item As GroupSelect = collection.Where(Function(i) i.RowNo = RowNo AndAlso i.GroupNo = GroupNo).SingleOrDefault()

If item Is Nothing Then
    Dim newItem As New GroupSelect()
    newItem.GroupNo = GroupNo
    newItem.RowNo = RowNo

    newItem.Value = Value

    collection.Add(newItem)
Else
    item.Value = Value
End If
```

`SingleOrDefault()` should be ideal in your case because it doesn't look like you will never have more than one item matching the criteria. But it might be a good idea to surround the query with with `Try..Catch`.